# what dose the '-d' option in watchify(a npm package ) mean?

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify, watchify

here is the package's link:https://www.npmjs.com/package/watchify
I saw an usage somewhere: "watchify -o js/bundle.js -v -d js/app.js".
I hope to know what dose the '-d' option mean.
Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/substack/watchify/issues/221 - look this issue

Answer (score 0):

According to watchify source code, it gets passed on to browserify, and taken
from https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage:

--debug -d  Enable source maps that allow you to debug your files
                   separately.

Comment: glad to hear you got the info you were looking for. as Jose's and my answers are practically the same, mark the one you like best as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Watchify uses browserify and includes the argument list for it:
  https://github.com/substack/watchify/blob/master/bin/args.js

Look at https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage

for more information.  As Andrey said, it sets up source maps for debugging.